FInding a path based on more parameters than just time
I'm trying to create some google maps variant that would give you the least polluted path based on a database storing a bunch of lat-long positions which represent polluted spots, the goal being to find a path that combines a good time and a low pollution level. All this would be based on OSM data.
Writing my own routing engine would be too complex.
I thought about modifying the OSM data by adding weight to the edges containing a polluted spot before applying an existing routing engine to it, meaning i'll need to associate a lat-long position with an edge which i don't know how to do.
I would be really grateful to anyone giving me an opinion about this method and/or any better one.
(PS: Please note that this must be scalable)
